# Does the inequality of the singular values $\sigma_j(A)\ge\sigma_j(B)$ imply $A^T A-B^T B\ge0$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ and $B$ be two matrices of dimension $n\times n$. Assume:
$$\sigma_j(A) \geq \sigma_j (B) \quad\text{for } j=1,\ldots,r, $$
where $\sigma_j(A)$ is the $j$-th largest singular value of $A$ and  $r=\min\{rank(A),rank(B)\}$. Can we say that the matrix $A^\top A-B^\top B$ is nonnegative definite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. 
Let
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix} 
8 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 6 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 4
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and 
$$
B = \begin{bmatrix} 
7 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 5
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Then 
$$
A^tA - B^t B = \begin{bmatrix} 
15 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 32 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -9
\end{bmatrix}
$$
which is not non-negative definite.